# Re indexing DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

How would I go about reindexing the purchase records of the DF to be indexed by store first, then by person? Thank you

```
purchase_1 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Chris',
                        'Item Purchased': 'Dog Food',
                        'Cost': 22.50})
purchase_2 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Kevyn',
                        'Item Purchased': 'Kitty Litter',
                        'Cost': 2.50})
purchase_3 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Vinod',
                        'Item Purchased': 'Bird Seed',
                        'Cost': 5.00})

df = pd.DataFrame([purchase_1, purchase_2, purchase_3],
                  index=['Store 1', 'Store 1', 'Store 2'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
df = df.set_index('Name', append=True)
```

Output:

```
               Cost Item Purchased
        Name                      
Store 1 Chris  22.5       Dog Food
        Kevyn   2.5   Kitty Litter
Store 2 Vinod   5.0      Bird Seed
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. That is what I was looking for. Sorry if I didn't explain it clearer.

Comment: @martinbshp Glad I could help.